# Debugging AngularJS, Splicing List

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Kind of 2 questions in 1 here, Finding Angular really hard to debug.
Seems like stuff just magically breaks and fixes itself.
For example I have an ajax call to delete a "site".
Worked fine, I was happy with it so I decided to add a bit of code to splice it from the list. Now my id come through as null.
I put a break point in In google chrome for my onClick() but it never gets hit.
Using MVC5 and angular
HTML

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Value
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>


<tr ng-repeat="site in sites">
    <td>
        {{site.Value}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="delete-{{site.Id}}" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteSite(site.id)">Delete</button>
    </td>

</tr>
```

​

Angular controller

```
ngApp.controller('siteController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

$http.post(ROOT + '/Site/LoadAll/')
          .success(function (result) {
              $scope.sites = result;
          }).
          error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              // log to console?
          });

$scope.deleteSite = function (id) {
    //$http.post(ROOT + 'SiteList/Delete/', JSON.stringify(id)) //null id
    //$http.post(ROOT + 'SiteList/Delete/', id) //Invalid JSON primitive: 5f6d794f-bf13-4480-9afd-3b10d7b6ae32.
    //$http.post(ROOT + 'Site/Delete/', { id: id } )
    $http.post(ROOT + '/Site/Delete/' + id)
        .success(function (result) {
            // log to console?
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // log to console?
        });


    for (var i = $scope.sites.lenght - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ($scope.sites[i].id == id)
        {
            $scope.sites.splice(i,1)
        }
    }
    //for(var i=0)
    // find the $scope.sites that matches the id
    // javascript re mpve that elemtne from the array
};}]);
```

Server controller

```
public JsonResult Delete(Guid id)
    {
        try
        {
            //var convertedID = new Guid(id);
            _siteService.Delete(id);
            return Json("OK", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json("Error" + e.Message);
        }

    }
```

So can anybody spot an issue here and how do you guys debug your Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a javascript, a http request and a asp.net mvc modelbinding flow to debug here.

**In javascript** i would add a few console.log statements. I use chrome for development and debugging. You could add a `console.log('site', i, id, $scope.sites);` in your "splice loop" to check if you get the expected result.

**Http traffic** can be monitored with chrome in the network tab or you can download fiddler2. Both will take a little playing around with to understand but once you get it, it's pretty straightforward. Pay attention to your form values in the request. It should hold a key `id` with the id value of the site.

In your **asp.net mvc application** you can set a breakpoint on your first `{` line of your action method and inspect the `id` variable to see if that holds the expected value.

Comment: That's what was holding me up it wouldn't go to the action because the `id` was null. I just passed the `site` object through instead and changed my method around a bit. Thanks for your help.